# NGINX: rewrite URL variable as subdomain

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting, subdomain, query-string

Is it possible to rewrite an URL on a NGINX server where the url variable becomes a virtual subdomain? Like this:

Original URL:
`https://subdomain.domain.com/index.html?id=123`

New URL:
`https://123.domain.com/`

I tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. There are many solutions for the reversed way, but I don't know if this is even possible. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you have a wildcard certificate, you can use a regular expression `server_name` to capture the subdomain. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Comment: What exactly do you want? Proxy such a request to that subdomain or get a 30x HTTP redirect?